# Split Data Every N Columns and rbind Using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data frame. In my data set. a, a1 and a2 are the exact same variable. However when you have the same names in r it automatically adds a 1 at the end of the name.

```
  df = data.frame(a = rnorm(4), b = rnorm(4), c = rnorm(4), a1 = rnorm(4), b1 = rnorm(4), c1 = rnorm(4), a2 = rnorm(4),
                b2 = rnorm(4), c2 = rnorm(4), date = seq(as.Date("2019-05-05"),as.Date("2019-05-08"), 1))
  print(df)



             a          b          c         a1         b1         a2         b2         c2       date
1 -1.0938097  1.3948486  1.2805904  1.6187439  1.0200681 -1.4335761 -0.4583526  0.3825598 2019-05-05
2 -0.3195004 -1.1281779 -2.1905902 -1.1693616 -0.9612850 -0.7502631 -0.5637997  0.3072459 2019-05-06
3 -0.2135026  0.7015042 -0.8271073 -0.1115213 -1.0378507  0.5620332 -2.0615450  1.7363142 2019-05-07
4  1.0413566 -1.1983207  0.9262545  0.6454741 -0.7874252  0.1904461  0.8970132 -1.4173619 2019-05-08
```

I would like to turn this data into long format where I split the data frame into chunks (a-c, a1-c1, a2-c2) and then rbind each subset. There is a key column called date at the end of the data.frame.

I would like the table to become the following.

```
       a          b          c       date
1   1.70236896  0.1847794  1.0642016 2019-05-05
2  -1.84604746  1.1229081  1.0550992 2019-05-06
3  -0.70185143 -0.8527223  1.3261573 2019-05-07
4  -0.47930296  0.2822001 -0.3271825 2019-05-08
5  -0.09950265 -0.1881748 -0.7482557 2019-05-05
6   0.72087483  2.0053211  1.1154889 2019-05-06
7  -1.83254875 -0.4060090 -0.2664467 2019-05-07
8  -0.17379130  0.6302901  1.5287194 2019-05-08
9   1.72706128 -1.4701842  1.1615761 2019-05-05
10  2.00246599  0.1306764 -1.8767190 2019-05-06
11  0.05263048  0.1173080  0.4293342 2019-05-07
12 -0.70024619  1.0677009 -0.2974141 2019-05-08
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need `melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^a", "^b", "^c"), value.name = c("a", "b", "c"))`

Comment: I think you're missing a `c1`

Comment: I added the C1. Thanks

Comment: akrun can you post your answer so I can give you cred. This worked great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^a", "^b", "^c"),
         value.name = c("a", "b", "c"))[, variable := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 1):

With R-base only:

```
vector = c('a', 'b', 'c')
df.new = list()
for (variable in vector) {
  var.group = grep(variable, colnames(df))
  df.new[[variable]] = stack(df[, var.group])[,1]
}
df.new =  as.data.frame(df.new)
df.new = cbind.data.frame(df.new, date=df$date)
print(df.new)
                  a          b          c       date
    1  -0.537778534 -0.5804655 -0.8866349 2019-05-05
    2  -1.891995399 -0.6454293 -0.4255403 2019-05-06
    3   0.710379004 -0.7718716 -0.5845242 2019-05-07
    4  -0.349523645 -1.4444619 -0.9783922 2019-05-08
    5  -0.558693367  0.2850591  1.3180083 2019-05-05
    6  -2.153964601 -1.8949987 -0.4039877 2019-05-06
    7  -1.652931301  0.6643048 -0.4555994 2019-05-07
    8  -0.657440968 -0.1361812 -0.3027680 2019-05-08
    9   1.423518807 -0.9561343 -0.8997554 2019-05-05
    10 -0.440000490  1.4045568 -1.3441805 2019-05-06
    11 -0.004766291 -0.5683855  0.2077830 2019-05-07
    12 -0.959219039 -0.1366399 -0.3789737 2019-05-08
```

Comment: The problem is I have 2000 variables! This is only a sample. Akrun's answer did the trick!

Comment: Indeed, I'll update my answer for R-base if it's useful to anybody in the future